# spotfire calculated column using over function

Tags: spotfire, data-transform

I want to create a calculated column "indicateur" that traces the boolean values
when I have a True, I increment the indicator by 1, however i want the false rows to have the value of the last true indicator.

and when i pass to a new ID, the incrementation starts from zero.

I already tried some spotfire expression using the over function but not getting the right results

```
case  
when [boolean] then sum(If([boolean],1,0)) over (Intersect([ID],AllPrevious([ID])))
else 0
end
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's doing exactly what you are describing you want it to do?

Comment: not really, with my expression, I only have values in the true cells, and also for every true occurence whithin the same id,  i get the same value

Comment: Oh, so the picture is what you wanted to happened, not what currently was happening. I didn't even bothering reading your expression because I assumed this was the output which looked correct.

Comment: no worries ! thanks for your attention and response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues here. Your case statement is sub setting the data... it will only calculate sums where boolean is true.

The main issue is the over statement though. Something like this should give the correct answer

```
sum(If([boolean],1,0)) over (Intersect([ID],AllPrevious([Timestamp])))
```

Comment: beautiful answer ! it remains correct even after playing with records order, thanks ;)